# Relative and absolute creating issue with other div

Tags: html, css

I am using two divs with position `relative` and position `absolute`. They are working fine but the problem is when I am placing another div below them it should start after the upper div/background image, but instead it is going behind. Here's the fiddle. I could not upload the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/630gLxfk/

here's the code:

```css
.banner{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image:url('../images/main.png');
  height: 100%;
}

.banner div{
  font-family: young;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: table;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}

.banner h1{
  font-size: 70px;
}

.logo{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204,0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div>
    <h1>Let's Move Together</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="logo" align="center">
  <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
<div style="">
  <h1>asdadadas</h1>
  <h1>asdadadas</h1>
  <h1>asdadadas</h1>
  <h1>asdadadas</h1>
  <h1>asdadadas</h1>
  <h1>asdadadas</h1>
  <h1>asdadadas</h1>
  <h1>asdadadasaa</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wanting the 'asdadadas' content below the title & donate button:

```
<div class="content-under">
<h1>asdadadas</h1>
<h1>asdadadas</h1>
<h1>asdadadas</h1>
<h1>asdadadas</h1>
<h1>asdadadas</h1>
<h1>asdadadas</h1>
<h1>asdadadas</h1>
<h1>asdadadasaa</h1>
</div>
```

Then in the CSS

```
.content-under {
    position:absolute;
    top:60%;
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/04ad4ok0/

Comment: thanks man sorry for the late reply was sleeping that time this perfectly did  the trick

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make this more simple. I hope it works for you.

1. You have a banner with background image.
2. On top of it you centre the title (I removed wrapper `<div>` for simplicity)
3. Then you have logo wrapper. Image is inline element, so if you want to center it, you apply `text-align: center` to the parent.

```css
.banner{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px; 
  
  background-image:url('http://placehold.it/200x40/');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  text-align: center;
}
.banner h1 {
  line-height: 80px; /* same as banner height*/
  font-size: 42px;
  color: white;
}

.logo{
  padding: 8px; /* giving a bit space */
  background-color: wheat;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <h1>Let's Move Together</h1>
</div>

<div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/160x80/"/>
</div>
<div class="other">
    <h1>asdadadas</h1>
    <h1>asdadadas</h1>
    <h1>asdadadas</h1>
    <h1>asdadadas</h1>
    <h1>asdadadas</h1>
    <h1>asdadadas</h1>
    <h1>asdadadas</h1>
    <h1>asdadadasaa</h1>
</div>
```